# K&R book exercise 1-9: Program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, prevchar;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != prevchar || prevchar != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        prevchar = c;
    }
}
```

How is this code working?

The code runs fine. I just need to understand its working.

Comment: Take a pen and paper and execute the program in your head noting the values of the variables. You need to do this if you do not understand how the programs work if you want to learn.

Comment: @gulpr I know that and I tried thiking about this program for a long time and still couldn't grasp how was it working. That's why I made this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but you must initialize `prevchar` to anything different from `' '`.  If you were to initialize `prevchar` to `' '`, initial blanks would be removed from the stream, which is not part of the assignment.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, prevchar = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != prevchar || prevchar != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        prevchar = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*replacing a string of blanks with a single blank* is implemented as removing blanks that immediately follow another bank.

The logic of the code is each byte read from the input stream is copied to the output stream if it differs from the previous byte or if the previous byte was not a blank (a space character `' '`).

The condition expressed as `(c != prevchar || prevchar != ' ')` is equivalent to

```
(!(c == prevchar && prevchar == ' '))
```

Which can be read as `c` is copied unless it is the same as the previous byte and the previous byte was also a blank.

It might be more readable to express this condition as

```
(c != ' ' || prevchar != ' ')
```

ie: `c` is not a blank or the previous byte was not a blank.

Comment: I did. The answer below is also insightful. Though yours worked better for understanding for me personally. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This book is problematic in many ways - the worst problem in this case is that it actively teaches bad practices like assignment inside `if` statements, which in turn is an incredibly well-known source of bugs. This was well-known bad practice in the year 1989 as well.

Futhermore, the code doesn't `return 0;` from main() invokes undefined behavior if executed on a C89 compiler, which was the target compiler of K&R. We shouldn't write code with undefined behavior bugs. This was well-known bad practice in the year 1989 as well.

In modern C, we can skip the `return 0;` in main(), but doing so in old C89 was never allowed.

`prevchar` must also be initialized before use. Initializing it to `0` or `EOF` would work since neither of those are valid string input form `stdin`.

A bug free, bad practice free, C89 compatible version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
  int prevchar = 0;
  for(int c=getchar(); c != EOF; c=getchar())
  {
    if (c != prevchar || prevchar != ' ')
    {
      putchar(c);
    }
    prevchar=c;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

- `c` is continuously reading character by character from stdin. It must be `int` since the constant `EOF` is `int`.
- In case `EOF` is encountered, the loop immediately breaks. Note that a `for` loop always checks the loop condition before executing the loop body.
- `prevchar` stores the previous character taken.
- The obscure part is `c != prevchar`, meaning that:

  - Either `c` is a space and `prevchar` is not, or vice versa. In either case, it is not two spaces in a row.
  - Or `c` is not a space and `prevchar` is, or vice versa. In which case the input it doing a transit between spaces and other character, so not two spaces in a row either.
  - Or `c` and `prevchar` are equal, in which case there might be 2 spaces in a row and the `prevchar != ' '` check is needed to rule that out.

For increased readability and less obscurity we could as well write:

```c
if (c == ' ' && prevchar == ' ')
  ; /* do nothing */
else
  putchar(c);
```

That's clearer and self-documenting, so it is much better programming than the original. We could also apply *De Morgan's laws* on that expression, although I don't think it improves readability:

```c
if (c != ' ' || prevchar != ' ')
  putchar(c);
```

Comment: Instead  `; /* do nothing */` I would suggest  `continue; /* do nothing */`

Comment: @gulpr No, `continue` is a spaghetti programming construct that should be avoided in all C programs, particularly when teaching beginners. It doesn't add anything of value here either - if updating `prevchar` when it is known to be the same value as `c` is oh-so-performance heavy, then it could be moved inside the `if` block. But anyone micro-optimizing code in such a manner, while it sits next to the huge bottleneck of taking input from stdin, is confused anyway.

Comment: It is much better than the `;` alone

Comment: @gulpr That's like saying "blue is much better than green, period". Do you have any actual arguments explaining why it is good? `continue` being bad practice has been addressed extensively in all the "goto considered harmful" debates since as far back as the 1960s, so any argument in favour of it will have to keep the spaghetti programming aspect in mind - yes we can write perfectly sounds and readable programs using `goto` and `continue`, but we actually don't need to.

Comment: @gulpr: `continue` will bypass the `prevchar = c;` statement, which has no bad side effect in this case and may well be your intent, but would be a logic error in other conditions.

Comment: Detail: "Initializing it to 0 or EOF would work since neither of those are valid string input form stdin."  --> OP's code is not working with C _strings_ even though the title mentions strings.  With general input, reading a _null character_ is rare, yet possible and so does not merit being part of "Initializing it to 0 or EOF ..." suggestion.  Given OP's code, `int prevchar = any_value_except_space;` works.  Sure 0 is OK here, but not because of its roll as a _null character_, but because it is not `' '`.

Comment: I get the working now and your modified code but tell me is K&R really that bad for C? I'm a beginner in this language and some stuff is still confusing to me. Also the book isn't really detailed but I do have some basic grasp in programming so I thought it's okay to learn from it.

Comment: @AyushKumar Yes it is really that bad. As noted twice in my answer, it had lot of conceptual errors that were wrong even at the point it was written. Additionally, there are a lot of typos and minor syntax errors for which errata exist. But the biggest problems are that it's so outdated, as well as the horrible, bad practice coding style. Unfortunately there's lots of fundamentalists referring to this book for nostalgia and religious reasons; you can't even criticize it with valid factual arguments without some old-timer showing up saying "no wrong!" without making any valid counter-arguments.